# DLL and ActiveX controls not availabe for domain users - Server 2008 32 bit

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions, windows-registry

I have a two applications that won't interface together correctly on a 64 bit system, so I am trying to commission a 32 bit Windows 2008 Server to use for the task.

When I log in to the server as a **local user**, the software runs correctly but it requires network resources to complete the task, so it won't complete.

When I log into the server as a **domain user**, the software doesn't run correctly.  One of the applications reports that it can't access the CSCUI.DLL.  The other application won't run at all with the error "ActiveX control 'PVExoplorerLib.PVExplorer' not referenced in this project...."

If I run the command "reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes /s /f cscui.dll" as the local user, it returns a list of keys that the DLL is registered in. e.g. "End of search: 13 match(es) found".  If I run the command from a domain user account, the result is "End of search: 0 match(es) found".

Can anyone help resolve what would be blocking the domain user from accessing the registry to use the DLL's and ActiveX controls?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this work on a client system?

Comment: Sounds simple,but does the software need to be run as a local administrator? Is the local user a local administrator?

Comment: The software needs to be run under a domain user account.    While the local machine accounts do run the software (both user and administrator accounts work), they don't have the required permissions to the network drives and SQL server.